# LDAP Search Filter for uid in Java

Tags: java, filter, ldap

I want to define a search filter for the user id in java, but I don't understand the right syntax. Here is my code:

```
 String searchFilter = searchAttribute + "=(|(" + "in" + ")(" + "ex" + "))" + name;
```

The filter should search e.g. after "in12345" or "ex12345"
My searchAttribute in this case would be the uid.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really a Java question but I think the resulting String is something like this:

```
(|(uid=in12345)(uid=ex12345))
```

You should probably get an LDAP browser and figure out the syntax and then figure out how to build it in Java.  This is also a place where [format](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/lang/string/java-string-format-example/) strings will help.